# Gnuplot legend order

Tags: gnuplot

Does somebody know how I can change the order within the key without changing the order of the plot commands? By default, the key has the same ordering as the titles of the individual plots.

For example: 
I plot first an error-band with filledcu, then the mean value as a solid line. Now I have the error-band title on top (in the key), followed by the title of the solid line. But I want to have it the other way round.

best wishes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use

```
set key invert
```

to change the ordering of the key entries.

Comment: thanks! this of course does not work if I want to plot several timeseries with shaded errorband. Still good to know

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Why shouldn't that work for several time series?

Comment: yes you are right it works when using transparent shadings. I sometimes did something like first drawing all the error-bands and on top the mean values (such that they are not hidden behind any error-shadings). 

The "set key invert" only inverts to order of the labels and does not provide the possibility to achieve a arbitrary odering in the legend.

Comment: Ok, in that case the solution of @mgilson is the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

There's no way that I know of without resorting to ugly hacks...  Here's one such ugly hack:

```
plot sin(x) with filledcurves notitle, \
     cos(x) with lines, \
     NaN with filledcurves title 'sin(x)' lc rgb "#ff0000"
```

Basically, we plot the first two plots as normal (except we remove the title from the first plot).  Then we make a "null" plot (`plot NaN`) with the same style and title that you want in the key...